# How to display date using C++?

Tags: function, date, messagebox

How can I display the date using the function "MessageBox"?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link for several different ways to get the date and time:
[Date & Time](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/datetimedisc.aspx)

Copied from site above:

Definition (from windows):

```
typedef struct _SYSTEMTIME {
    WORD wYear;
    WORD wMonth;
    WORD wDayOfWeek;
    WORD wDay;
    WORD wHour;
    WORD wMinute;
    WORD wSecond;
    WORD wMilliseconds;
} SYSTEMTIME, *PSYSTEMTIME, *LPSYSTEMTIME;
```

Implementation:

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetSystemTime(&st);
// You format how you want
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime::Now;
MessageBox::Show(dateTime.ToString());
```

Other `ToXString()` functions can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_methods%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For example like this (I assumed you asked about native Windows API):

```
// Get current time
SYSTEMTIME now;
GetLocalTime(&now);

// Format the date using the default user language
TCHAR buffer[1024];
GetDateFormat(
    MAKELCID(LANG_USER_DEFAULT, SORT_DEFAULT), 
    0, 
    &now, 
    NULL, 
    buffer, 
    1024
);

// Show it in a message box
MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP, buffer, _T("Today"), MB_OK);
```

It's also possible to ask `GetDateFormat` to calculate the buffer length required to store the output.  To do that pass `NULL` and `0` as last two parameters:

```
int length = GetDateFormat(
    MAKELCID(LANG_USER_DEFAULT, SORT_DEFAULT), 
    0, 
    &now, 
    NULL, 
    NULL, 
    0
);
```